# Cyclomatic Complexity and variants

Tags: java, metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

Whats the diferrence between essential, design complexity, extended cyclomatic complexity, cyclomatic complexity?

I'm checking this metrics using a IntelliJ IDEA plugin.

[image]

Comment: how do you run this complexity analysis in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Mobigital Most pobably he is running a IntellIJ plug-in named 'MetricsReloaded'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Overview**

*Design complexity* measures the dependency of a method on other methods; *cyclomatic complexity* measures the number of distinct paths through a method; and *extended cyclomatic complexity* adds a control logic metric to represent "the minimal number of tests necessary to completely exercise a method's control flow."

**Details**

[**Design complexity**](https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded/blob/master/stockmetrics/metricsDescriptions/metricsDescriptions/DesignComplexity.html)

> This metric reports the design complexity of a method. The design
>   complexity is related to how interlinked a method's control flow is
>   with calls to other methods. Design complexity ranges from 1 to V(g),
>   the cyclomatic complexity of the method. Design complexity also
>   represents the minimal number of tests necessary to exercise the
>   integration of the method with the methods it calls.

[**Cyclomatic complexity**](https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded/blob/master/stockmetrics/metricsDescriptions/metricsDescriptions/CyclomaticComplexity.html)

> This metric reports the cyclomatic complexity of each non-abstract
>   method. Cyclomatic complexity is a graph-theoretic measure of the
>   number of distinct paths through each method. In practice, it is
>   basically 1 + the number of branch points in the method.

**[Extended cyclomatic complexity](https://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-complexity.html)**

> This metric reports the extended cyclomatic complexity of each
>   non-abstract method. Cyclomatic complexity is a graph-theoretic
>   measure of the number of distinct paths through each method, augmented
>   by a measure of the complexity of the decision points. In practice, it
>   is basically 1 + the number of branch points in the method plus the
>   number of logical 'and' and 'or' operations. Cyclomatic complexity
>   also represents the minimal number of tests necessary to completely
>   exercise a method's control flow.